# Is there a prayer I should say before taking off in a plane?

Tags: tefilla, technology, travel

On Monday, I am going to take a flight. I would imagine I should say the Shehecheyanu when I land, thanking God for my continued existence, but is there a blessing I could or should say when I take off, asking God for safety?

Comment: "I know I should say the Shehecheyanu when I land" How do you know this? Please [edit] to clarify. I've never heard of that before.

Comment: Should this be closed as RFP?

Comment: If you specifically want a bracha, how about a shehakol on the water and dramamine?

Comment: @Danno That would probably be a bracha levatala, as you aren't drinking the water for thirst.

Comment: @DoubleAA before I fly my mouth gets very dry; that's why I put the water first, then the dramamine.

Comment: @rosends that wouldn’t help. If just drinking the water to down the pill, then no Bracha is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most say the traditional [Prayer for Travel](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/379130/jewish/Text-of-the-Travelers-Prayer.htm).

(From the Chabad site):

> May it be Your will, G-d, our G-d and the G-d of our fathers, that You should lead us in peace and direct our steps in peace, and guide us in peace, and support us in peace, and cause us to reach our destination in life, joy, and peace (If one intends to return immediately, one adds: and return us in peace). Save us from every enemy and ambush, from robbers and wild beasts on the trip, and from all kinds of punishments that rage and come to the world. May You confer blessing upon the work of our hands and grant me grace, kindness, and mercy in Your eyes and in the eyes of all who see us, and bestow upon us abundant kindness and hearken to the voice of our prayer, for You hear the prayers of all. Blessed are You G-d, who hearkens to prayer.

You can still find some old prayer books that have a specially-composed prayer for air travel, but most people today just use the standard prayer for travel.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough, but I meant a b'racha (Baruch atah Adonai Eloheinu Melech HaOlam…)

Comment: That is a blessing. It ends "Blessed are You G-d, who hearkens to prayer.".

Comment: @msh210 Does it have Malkhut?

Comment: Shabbat @Shalom :) - suggestion to add when during the flight you should say *Tefillat Haderech*.  OP asked "when I take off", but, it's unclear to me, and perhaps, him/her when, exactly that is.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 when taking off, you're *praying* for a safe trip, not *thanking* God for something you have.

Comment: @Shalom Are prayers for the future never couched in a text beginning "Barukh Attah [etc.]"? I didn't know that.